# Вычисление остатка от деления в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, математика

Вполне понятно, что:

```
5 % 2 // будет 1
4 % 2 // будет 0
```

Но, почему:

```
1 % 7 // будет 1
2 % 7 // будет 2
3 % 7 // будет 3 и так далее и тому подобное`
```

Непонятно, кто сможет объяснит?

В последнее время встречаю подобное для вычислений и сам уже использую, но как это работает не могу понять.

Comment: @Санаев "в интернете полно объяснений" - как мне кажется, без ссылки на источник в Интернет, Ваш комментарий мягко говоря - бесполезен.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов первая же ссылка!!! https://otvet.mail.ru/question/64174313

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому он что не связан с программированием.

Comment: @mymedia: [первая редакция о javascript спрашивает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/734171/1). [Поведение `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Остаток_от_деления_%28%29) разни́тся между языками программирования и не такое очевидное как может показаться. Посмотрите ссылки из моих комментариев.

Comment: Редко я такое говорю, но учите арифметику. Деление с остатком, вроде бы, в начальной школе проходят.

Answer (score 16):

Оператор **`%`** работает как нормальный оператор возвращающий остаток от деления. При `a % b` `a` делится нацело на `b` и все что остается возвращается. Числа 1, 2, и 3 меньше 7, поэтому нацело они на 7 не делятся (результат их деления на 7 нацело равен нулю) и в остатке остаются сами числа

```
1 % 7 = ноль целых и один в остатке
2 % 7 = ноль целых и два в остатке
3 % 7 = ноль целых и три в остатке
```

Comment: Спасибо, давно мучает этот вопрос. Теперь понятно.

Comment: @RiseUp: если хотите снова запутаться, то попробуйте отрицательные числа (`%` операция является взятием остатка в Питоне (`0<=(a%b)<b`), но не в Си(99), где (`a % b`) может быть отрицательным: `-1 % 7 == 6` в Питоне и `-1 % 7 == -1` в Си(99). Деление с остатком определяется формулой: `a = b * (a / b) + (a % b)` плюс условие `0<=(a%b)<b` — это достаточно, чтобы уникально получить `a/b` и `a%b`. В Си(99) `-a/b == -(a/b)` (симметрия, нарушает свойство остатка), в Питоне `(a+k*b)//b == (a//b)+ k` (периодичность, ведёт к "настоящему" "делению по модулю" https://stackoverflow.com/a/1907889/4279

Comment: @RiseUp: чтобы получить остаток и в Си, можно  [`(b + (a % b)) % b`](https://ideone.com/vdF6OY) формулу использовать. См. [Деление с остатком](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC), [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division)

Comment: @jfs, благодарю за восстановление математической справедливости. Если не секрет - а исторически, кто у программистов придумал считать остатки от отрицательных чисел отрицательными и зачем?

Comment: @АлександрБелинский значение `a%b` следует из свойств `a/b`. До C99 a/b зависело от реализации. C99 к нулю округляет потому что Fortran так делал, который вероятно в свою очередь использовал то что на CPU быстрее (про Фортран—[со слов человека, который черновик стандарта правил](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/comp.std.c/hjGK3cx_I-o/_zB17QyViDgJ)<-здесь ещё более robust формулы, для остатка в Си) https://stackoverflow.com/q/3602827/4279

Answer (score 9):

Потому что 1/7 = 0, а остаток от деления, соответственно будет 1 - (7*0), то есть 1

Answer (score 0):

1,2,3 на 7 не делятся значит будет 0, а так как оператор берет остатки от деления, то он и выводит эти числа

Comment: ```Что-что??```

Answer (score 0):

по сей день актуален для многих новичков вопрос!
формула по теореме такая: `a = b*c +r`
где:

- `a` - делимое (что делим)
- `b` - делитель (на что делим)
- `с` - целое число до запятой от результата деления (поэтому в случае `a<b` всегда будет 0 ноль)
- `r` - то, что нужно прибавить, чтобы формула наша сошлась (тот самый измученный нами "остаток"! :))

Например, если мы хотим увидеть остаток от деления `a=1` на `b=6`:

```
1 = 6*c + r
(с = 1/6=0,###)
```

поэтому

```
1 = 6*0 + r
r = 1 - 0 = 1
a%b=1
```

Второй пример когда `a>b`,
`a=8`, `b=3`:

```
8 = 3*с + r
(с = 8/3=2,###)
```

поэтому

```
8 = 3*2 + r
r = 8 - 6 = 2
a%b=2
```

Этот самый расчудесный остаток % при условии a<b может использоваться, например, в коде js для универсальных циклов с массивами (таких как зацикленные слайдеры и т.п., где количество элементов в массиве может изменяться и не должно влиять на исполняемый код)