# Разница оператора % (остаток от деления или "modulo") в Python и Java

Tags: java, python, массивы, циклы

Столкнулся с проблемой. Нужно было на Java циклически обоходить  массив. Написал нечто подобное:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int mySuperPuperInt = 4096;
        String mySuperPuperArray[] = {
                "My",
                "Awesome",
                "String",
                "Content"
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < mySuperPuperInt; i++) {
            System.out.println(mySuperPuperArray[i % mySuperPuperArray.length]);
        }
    }
```

Все заработало, массив перебирался - я доволен. Однако, как только начинаю перебирать в цикле отрицательные числа, код перестал работать и выдал ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Оказалось, оператор % выдает отрицательные значения, если левый операнд тоже отрицательный, что изрядно меня удивило.

```
for (int i =-8192; i < -4096; i++) {
            System.out.println(mySuperPuperArray[i % mySuperPuperArray.length]);
}
```

Для сравнения, в привычном Python, аналогичный код

```
for i in range(-8192, 0):
    print(i % 4)
```

Выдает только положительные значения включая 0.
Почему 2 одинаковых оператора предназначенных для одного и того же в двух языках ведут себя по-разному, и зачем это нужно?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Вычисление остатка от деления](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/734171/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это поведение описано в спецификации - [JLS 15.17.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3):

> The remainder operation for operands that are integers after binary
>   numeric promotion (§5.6.2) produces a result value such that
>   (a/b)*b+(a%b) is equal to a.
>
> This identity holds even in the special case that the dividend is the
>   negative integer of largest possible magnitude for its type and the
>   divisor is -1 (the remainder is 0).
>
> It follows from this rule that **the result of the remainder operation**
>   **can be negative only if the dividend is negative, and can be positive**
>   **only if the dividend is positive**. Moreover, the magnitude of the
>   result is always less than the magnitude of the divisor.

Остаток от деления должен иметь тот же знак, что и делимое.

Comment: В Питоне используется дополнительное условие: [`0<=(a%b)<b`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/734171/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-javascript#comment1117545_734173), которое уникальное решение для `a = b * (a / b) + (a % b)` гарантирует (настоящий [остаток от деления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC))