# Python 3 остаток от деления

Tags: python-3.x

Почему в Python остаток от деления 45 на 60 равен 45?

```
45 % 60 = 45
```

Comment: А как иначе? Таково уж обычное определение остатка. `n = q * d + rem` и  `0 ≤ rem < |d|`

Comment: При делении с остатком остаток всегда должен быть меньше делителя.

Comment: 45 делим на 60. Челое получается 0, а остаток 45 (45/60-х или 9/12-х или 3/4-х или 0.75-х :))

Comment: А сколько вы ожидаете?

Comment: @VladSpirin: `45 % -60 == -15` и `-15 > -60`

Comment: [комментарии в тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/734171/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-javascript/734173#comment1117545_734173)

Answer (score 3):

Потому что ближайшее целое число, которое можно нацело (без остатка) разделить на 60 - это 0. Соответственно остаток от деления 45.