# Круговое передвижение по карте

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, canvas

Есть очень большой двумерный массив - игровая карта. 
Есть маленький двумерный массив - текущая, видимая часть игровой карты.
Необходимо реализвать круговое (зацикленное) передвижение видимой части игровой карты. Чтобы при досттижении конца Глобальной карты, начинало отображаться начало Глобальной карты и так по кругу, в любую из сторон

Ниже, в собственном ответе, я показываю свою реализацию. Cделал как мог.  Но хочется увидеть вариант от профи).

Comment: "Есть двумерный массив. Необходимо реализвать круговое (зацикленное) передвижение по карте." - как эти два предложения связаны друг с другом?

Comment: @AnT Они связаны друг с другом в мозгу автора.

Comment: @AnT, спасибо, дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @Igor, дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @Дмытрык Э-э-э... Лучше не стало.

Comment: @Igor, перефразировал еще раз)

Comment: @Дмытрык Вот. Теперь дело проясняется.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам надо переписать зубодробительный код в функции `getGlobalMapSector`. Если я правильно понял, она выбирает из большого двумерного массива двумерный кусок с заворачиванием через границы большого массива. Все, что для этого нужно, - текущее положение левого-верхнего угла меньшего массива в большем и обращение к элементам большего массива с использованием остатка от деления.

Вот одномерный случай:

```js
var sizeLarge = 10;
var sizeSmall = 4;
var start = 0;

var large = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sizeLarge; i++) {
  large.push(i + 1);
}

function getSmall() {
  if (start < 0)
    start += sizeLarge;
  var small = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < sizeSmall; j++) {
    small.push(large[(start + j) % sizeLarge]);
  }
  return small;
}

function showSmall() {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(getSmall()));
}
showSmall();
```

```html
<button onclick="start--;showSmall()">Left</button>
<button onclick="start++;showSmall()">Right</button>
```

Comment: У меня главная трудность возникла в тот момент, когда центр видимой части карты был близок какому-либо углу Глобальной карты. Приходилось делать выборку с разных частей Глобальной карты, а не по порядку. Мне в этом как-то поможет использование остатка от деления?

Comment: Допустим длина Глобальной карты 30, видимой 11. Центр видимой карты приходится на 2:28. В таком случае, для корректного отображения видимой карты, необходимо сделать выборку со всех углов Глобальной карты

Comment: @Дмытрык Вам понятна идея для одномерного случая - в ответе?

Comment: С работой кода, я разобрался. А вот откуда берется эта "магия", почему она работает -  я пока не понимаю) Но это больше вопрос к фундаментальным знаниям

Comment: почитал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/734171/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-javascript - теперь стала понятна магия)

Answer (score 2):

Выборка видимой части карты происходит в функции `getGlobalMapSector`. Все остальное для визуализации

```js
const GlobalMap = [];
const numSection = 30; //длина GlobalMap
const viewNumSection = 11; //длина видимой части карты
//центр видимой части карты
const centerMap = {
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
};
//видимая часть карта
let currentMap = [];



const isoCoords = {
  x: 0,
  y: 200,
};
const tileWidth = 36;
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const viewX = document.getElementById('rombX')
const viewY = document.getElementById('rombY')
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveOnMap);
const colors = {
  0: "green",
  1: "blue",
  2: "black",
  3: "yellow",
};

for (let i = 0; i < numSection; i++) {
  const row = [];
  GlobalMap.push(row);
  for (let h = 0; h < numSection; h++) {
    const obj = {
      x: i,
      y: h,
      type: Math.floor(Math.random() * 4),
    };
    row.push(obj);
  }
}

currentMap = getGlobalMapSector();
drawMap();

function getGlobalMapSector() {
  let rangeArr = [];
  let length = GlobalMap.length;
  let rangeSize = viewNumSection;
  rangeSize = rangeSize % 2 !== 0 ? rangeSize : rangeSize + 1; //костыль
  let halfSize = Math.floor(rangeSize / 2);
  let minX = centerMap.x - halfSize;
  let minY = centerMap.y - halfSize;
  let startX = minX;
  let startY = minY;
  let endX = minX + rangeSize;
  let endY = minY + rangeSize;

  //передвижение внутри карты
  if (
    minX >= 0 &&
    minY >= 0 &&
    minX + rangeSize <= length &&
    minY + rangeSize <= length
  ) {
    // console.log("передвижение внутри карты")
    let endX = minX + rangeSize;
    let endY = minY + rangeSize;
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(minX, endX, minY, endY, rangeArr);
    rangeArr = formResultMap(rangeArr, rangeSize);
  }
  //верхний левый угол карты
  else if (minX < 0 && minY < 0) {
    let startX = length - Math.abs(minX);
    let endX = length;
    let startY = length - Math.abs(minY);
    let endY = length;
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    startY = 0;
    endY = 0 + (rangeSize - (length - (length - Math.abs(minY))));
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    startX = 0;
    endX = 0 + (rangeSize - (length - (length - Math.abs(minX))));
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    startY = length - Math.abs(minY);
    endY = length;
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    sortArr_standart(rangeArr);
    changeArr(rangeArr, length - Math.abs(minX), "x");
    rangeArr = formResultMap(rangeArr, rangeSize);
    rangeArr = sortArr_Y(rangeArr, length - Math.abs(minY));
  }
  //нижний правый угол карты
  else if (minX + rangeSize >= length && minY + rangeSize >= length) {
    let startX = minX;
    let endX = length;
    let startY = minY;
    let endY = length;
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    startX = 0;
    endX = minX + rangeSize - length;
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    startY = 0;
    endY = minY + rangeSize - length;
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    startX = minX;
    endX = length;
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    sortArr_standart(rangeArr);
    changeArr(rangeArr, minX, "x");
    rangeArr = formResultMap(rangeArr, rangeSize);
    rangeArr = sortArr_Y(rangeArr, minY);
  }
  //верхний правый угол карты
  else if (minX < 0 && minY + rangeSize > length) {
    let startX = length - Math.abs(minX);
    let endX = length;
    let startY = minY;
    let endY = length;
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    startX = 0;
    endX = 0 + (rangeSize - (length - (length - Math.abs(minX))));
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    startY = 0;
    endY = minY + rangeSize - length;
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    startX = length - Math.abs(minX);
    endX = length;
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    sortArr_standart(rangeArr);
    changeArr(rangeArr, length - Math.abs(minX), "x");
    rangeArr = formResultMap(rangeArr, rangeSize);
    rangeArr = sortArr_Y(rangeArr, minY);
  }
  //нижний левый угол карты
  else if (minY < 0 && minX + rangeSize > length) {
    let startX = minX;
    let endX = length;
    let startY = length - Math.abs(minY);
    let endY = length;
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    startY = 0;
    endY = 0 + (rangeSize - (length - (length - Math.abs(minY))));
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    startX = 0;
    endX = minX + rangeSize - length;
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    startY = length - Math.abs(minY);
    endY = length;
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    sortArr_standart(rangeArr);
    changeArr(rangeArr, length - Math.abs(minX), "x");
    rangeArr = formResultMap(rangeArr, rangeSize);
    rangeArr = sortArr_Y(rangeArr, minX);
  }
  //по центру верхней линии карты
  else if (minX < 0 && minY >= 0 && minY + rangeSize <= length) {
    let startX = length - Math.abs(minX);
    let endX = length;
    let startY = minY;
    let endY = minY + rangeSize;
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    startX = 0;
    endX = 0 + (rangeSize - (length - (length - Math.abs(minX))));
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    sortArr_standart(rangeArr);
    changeArr(rangeArr, length - Math.abs(minX), "x");
    rangeArr = formResultMap(rangeArr, rangeSize);
    rangeArr = sortArr_Y(rangeArr, minX);
  }
  //по центру нижней линии карты
  else if (
    minY >= 0 &&
    minY + rangeSize < length &&
    minX >= 0 &&
    minX + rangeSize > length
  ) {
    let startX = minX;
    let endX = length;
    let startY = minY;
    let endY = minY + rangeSize;
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    startX = 0;
    endX = minX + rangeSize - length;
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    sortArr_standart(rangeArr);
    changeArr(rangeArr, minX, "x");
    rangeArr = formResultMap(rangeArr, rangeSize);
  }
  //по центру правой линии
  else if (
    minX >= 0 &&
    minX + rangeSize < length &&
    minY >= 0 &&
    minY + rangeSize > length
  ) {
    let startX = minX;
    let endX = minX + rangeSize;
    let startY = minY;
    let endY = length;
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    startY = 0;
    endY = minY + rangeSize - length;
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    sortArr_standart(rangeArr);
    rangeArr = formResultMap(rangeArr, rangeSize);
    rangeArr = sortArr_Y(rangeArr, minY);
  }
  //по центру левой линии
  else if (minY < 0 && minX >= 0 && minX + rangeSize <= length) {
    startX = minX;
    endX = minX + rangeSize;
    startY = length - Math.abs(minY);
    endY = length;
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    startY = 0;
    endY = 0 + (rangeSize - (length - (length - Math.abs(minY))));
    rangeArr = getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, rangeArr);
    sortArr_standart(rangeArr);
    rangeArr = formResultMap(rangeArr, rangeSize);
    rangeArr = sortArr_Y(rangeArr, length - Math.abs(minY));
  }
  let center = rangeArr.length - 1 - halfSize;
  let centerSection = rangeArr[center][center];
  centerMap.x = centerSection.x;
  centerMap.y = centerSection.y;
  return rangeArr;

  //сортирую элементы по Х и по У
  function sortArr_standart(arr) {
    arr.sort((a, b) => {
      let z = a.x - b.x;
      if (z == 0) {
        return a.y - b.y;
      } else {
        return z;
      }
    });
  }
  //сортирую массив по У
  function sortArr_Y(arr, num) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      let g = arr[i];
      changeArr(g, num, "y");
    }
    return arr;
  }

  //перекидываю с конца массива в начало необходимые елементы
  //num - число, начиная с которого нужно переместить елементы
  function changeArr(arr, num, os) {
    let g = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      let sector = arr[i];
      if (sector[os] >= num) {
        g = arr.splice(i, arr.length);
        break;
      }
    }
    for (let h = g.length - 1; h >= 0; h--) {
      arr.unshift(g[h]);
    }
  }
  //делаю выборку из исходного двумерного массива
  function getSectorMapList(startX, endX, startY, endY, arr) {
    for (let x = startX; x < endX; x++) {
      for (let y = startY; y < endY; y++) {
        arr.push(GlobalMap[x][y]);
      }
    }
    return arr;
  }

  //формирую двумерный массив из исходного списка
  function formResultMap(arr, size) {
    let count = 0;
    let itogArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      let f = [];
      itogArr.push(f);
      for (let h = 0; h < size; h++) {
        itogArr[i][h] = arr[count];
        count++;
      }
    }
    return itogArr;
  }

}

// меняет значение centerMap, currentMap
function moveOnMap(way) {
  let step = 2;
  let nowX = centerMap.x;
  let nowY = centerMap.y;
  if (way == "top") {
    centerMap.x = nowX + step;
    if (nowX + step > GlobalMap.length - 1) {
      centerMap.x = nowX + step - GlobalMap.length;
    }
  } else if (way === "bottom") {
    centerMap.x = nowX - step;
    if (nowX - step < 0) {
      centerMap.x = GlobalMap.length - Math.abs(nowX - step);
    }
  } else if (way === "left") {
    centerMap.y = nowY - step;
    if (nowY - step < 0) {
      centerMap.y = GlobalMap.length - Math.abs(nowY - step);
    }
  } else if (way === "right") {
    centerMap.y = nowY + step;
    if (nowY + step > GlobalMap.length - 1) {
      centerMap.y = nowY + step - GlobalMap.length;
    }
  }
  currentMap = getGlobalMapSector();
  drawMap();
}

function drawMap() {
  let mapArr = currentMap;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
  let tileHeight = tileWidth / 2;
  let halfHeight = tileHeight / 2;
  let startX = isoCoords.x;
  let startY = isoCoords.y;
  let startCenterX = startX + tileHeight;
  let startCenterY = startY;

  for (let i = 0; i < mapArr.length; i++) {
    for (let h = 0; h < mapArr[i].length; h++) {
      let centerX = startCenterX + 2 * halfHeight * (i + h);
      let centerY = startCenterY - halfHeight * (i - h);
      currentMap[i][h].centerX = centerX;
      currentMap[i][h].centerY = centerY;
      drawRectAroundCenter(centerX, centerY, mapArr[i][h].type);
    }
  }

  function drawRectAroundCenter(centerX, centerY, grid) {
    const step = 0;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = colors[grid];
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY - halfHeight + step);
    ctx.lineTo(centerX + step - tileHeight, centerY);
    ctx.lineTo(centerX, centerY + halfHeight - step);
    ctx.lineTo(centerX + tileHeight - step, centerY);
    ctx.lineTo(centerX, centerY - halfHeight + step);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

const mouseCoords = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
};

function getCursorPositionOnScene(event) {
  const clientX = event.clientX;
  const clientY = event.clientY;
  const position = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const mouseX = Math.floor(clientX - position.left);
  const mouseY = Math.floor(clientY - position.top);
  mouseCoords.x = mouseX;
  mouseCoords.y = mouseY;
  return;
}

function getTileCoordsOnMap() {
  const halfHeight = tileWidth / 2 / 2;
  const isoX = isoCoords.x;
  const isoY = isoCoords.y;
  const stepX = mouseCoords.x - isoX;
  const stepY = mouseCoords.y - isoY;
  const topX = 0.5 * stepX - stepY + isoX;
  const topY = 0.5 * stepY - stepX / 4 + isoY;
  const downX = 0.5 * stepX + stepY + isoX;
  const downY = 0.25 * stepX + 0.5 * stepY + isoY;

  let q = Math.pow(topX - isoX, 2) + Math.pow(topY - isoY, 2);
  const l = halfHeight * Math.sqrt(5);
  const lineTop = Math.sqrt(q);
  const rombX = Math.floor(lineTop / l);

  q = Math.pow(downX - isoX, 2) + Math.pow(downY - isoY, 2);
  const lineDown = Math.sqrt(q);
  const rombY = Math.floor(lineDown / l);

  return (coords = {
    x: rombX,
    y: rombY,
  });
}

function mouseMoveOnMap(event) {
  getCursorPositionOnScene(event);
  if (!checkMouseCoordsOnMap()) return;
  const rombCoords = getTileCoordsOnMap();
  const tile = currentMap[rombCoords.x][rombCoords.y]

  viewX.innerText = "X:" + tile.x;
  viewY.innerText = "Y:" + tile.y;
}
const borderIsoMap = {
  left: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  top: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  right: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  bottom: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
};
setBorderIsoMap();

function setBorderIsoMap() {
  const currentLength = currentMap.length;
  const height = tileWidth / 2;
  borderIsoMap.left.x = isoCoords.x;
  borderIsoMap.left.y = isoCoords.y;
  borderIsoMap.top.x = borderIsoMap.left.x + (tileWidth * currentLength) / 2;
  borderIsoMap.top.y = borderIsoMap.left.y - (height * currentLength) / 2;
  borderIsoMap.right.x = borderIsoMap.left.x + tileWidth * currentLength;
  borderIsoMap.right.y = borderIsoMap.left.y;
  borderIsoMap.bottom.x = borderIsoMap.top.x;
  borderIsoMap.bottom.y = borderIsoMap.left.y + (height * currentLength) / 2;
}

function checkMouseCoordsOnMap() {
  const coords = borderIsoMap;
  const left = coords.left;
  const top = coords.top;
  const right = coords.right;
  const bottom = coords.bottom;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "transparent";
  ctx.moveTo(left.x, left.y);
  ctx.lineTo(top.x, top.y);
  ctx.lineTo(right.x, right.y);
  ctx.lineTo(bottom.x, bottom.y);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  return ctx.isPointInPath(mouseCoords.x, mouseCoords.y);
}
```

```css
#scene {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
}

.bottom {
  bottom: 70px;
  left: 80px;
}

.left {
  top: 80px;
  left: 90px;
}

.top {
  right: 80px;
  top: 80px;
}

.right {
  bottom: 70px;
  right: 60px;
}

#rombX {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

#rombY {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="scene">
  <canvas id='canvas' width="400px" height="400px"></canvas>
  <button class="left" type="button" onclick="moveOnMap('left')">left</button>
  <button class="top" type="button" onclick="moveOnMap('top')">top</button>
  <button class="right" type="button" onclick="moveOnMap('right')">right</button>
  <button class="bottom" type="button" onclick="moveOnMap('bottom')">bottom</button>
  <div id="rombX">X: -1</div>
  <div id="rombY">Y: -1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Мельтешит красиво. А делать-то что оно должно?