# Перемещение по отрезку

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

У меня есть отрезок от i1 до i2
Мне нужно научится перемещатся по этому отрезку по кругу.
Если от 0 до 10 отрезок, я стою на индексе 2 и сдвинусь на -3, то окажусь на 10 индексе
Если сдвинусь на -14, то окажусь на 10 индексе
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также я могу двигаться и в правую сторону.

```js
/**
 * Функция для сдвига индекса
 * @param {number} length - Длина элементов
 * @param {number} index - Индекс текущего элемента
 * @param {number} shift - Сдвиг
 */
function shiftDigit(length, index, shift) {
  const indexSumShift = index + shift;
  if (indexSumShift < 0) {
    return length + indexSumShift;
  }
  return (index + shift) % length;
}

console.log(shiftDigit(11, 3, -5));
```

Мой код не имеет особого смысла, потому что я запутался

**UPD:** Я подумал, правильнее будет ещё указать, с какого значения индекс отрезка начинается и где заканчивается:

```js
/**
 * Функция для сдвига индекса
 * @param {number} start - Начало отрезка
 * @param {number} end - Конец отрезка
 * @param {number} index - Индекс текущего элемента
 * @param {number} shift - Сдвиг
 */
function shiftDigit(start, end, index, shift) {

}

console.log(shiftDigit(0, 10, 3, -15));
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Круговое передвижение по карте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/929446/%d0%9a%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: @Дмытрык, не совсем та же задача

Comment: @Grundy - ну, не знаю. На основании тамошнего ответа, дал ответ здесь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приводим диапазон к 0..size-1.
Прибавляем сдвиг. Если результат отрицательный, то после взятия модуля он лежит в диапазоне -size..-1, приводим его к положительному добавлением size.
Второй раз берём модуль на случай, если результат был положительный.
Приводим обратно к start...end

```js
  function shiftDigit(start, end, index, shift) {
       let size = end - start + 1;
       return start + ((index - start + shift) % size + size) % size;
   }     

   console.log(shiftDigit(0, 10, 3, -15));
   console.log(shiftDigit(0, 10, 3, 15));
```

Comment: нет смысла подбирать `n`- достаточно получить отрицательный остаток и добавить `size`

Comment: Работает как-то магическим образом, не понимаю, можно объяснить?

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо, негде было проверить, как JS обращается с отрицательными.

Comment: @MBo я вообще реализовывал шифр Цезаря, хотел сдвигать буквы алфавита. И решил сделать сдвиг и в минус

Comment: - Бедный Цезарь.

Answer (score 3):

смотреть метод `doShift`. Все остальное для визуализации

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      length: 5,
      activeIndex: 2,
      multi: 2
    }
  },
  methods: {
    doShift(active, shift, length) {
      const z = (active + shift) % length
      this.activeIndex = z < 0 ? length + z : z
    }
  },

});
```

```css
.index {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.control {
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
<div id="app">
<div class="wrap">
  <div v-for="i in length" class="index" :class="activeIndex === i-1 ? 'active' : ''">{{i-1}}</div>
</div>
  <button v-for="i in length" class="control" @click="doShift(activeIndex, i*multi, length)">+{{i*multi}}</button>
  <button v-for="i in length" class="control" @click="doShift(activeIndex, +('-' +i*multi), length)">-{{i*multi}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, вы уверены, что это будет работать при больших значениях? +100, -200

Comment: добавил в код множител (для шага) - проверяйте

Comment: Да, увидел, тоже работает, классно